# Catching a .xml file in a folder with changing name

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to catch a .XML file before it gets deleted when you close down a window. Is it possible to write a script that catches this file and saves it to a path even though the file placement is in randomly generated folders but in the same general path and with the same name
Eg: c:\users%username%\appdata\local\temp\print\report"random generated number"\download

I'm new to Programming and only made .bat files before

*EDIT*
I've successfully created a batch file that copies and saves the files that I need, however I want to have the Batch file run through a Hotkey is this possible in any way. I have tried the shortcut version and added a shortcut in the properties tab but with no success unfortunately.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "glob" module to find the file and "shutil" to copy the file to the destination you want. An example script would be as follows

```
import glob
import shutil

# output directory must exist 
dest = "results\\"
search = "c:\\Users\\User\\appdata\\local\\temp\\print\\report\\*\\download\\*.xml"
for file in glob.glob(search):
    shutil.copy(file, dest)
```